# How can I add multiple keys to listen in python turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to put more keys in the python turtle but every time I do that it tells me an error. Is there any way I can do it with multiple keys?
Code:

```
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(tic.one, "1")
screen.onkey(tic.two, "2")
screen.onkey(tic.three, "3")
```

Code I want:

```
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(tic.one, "1, t")
screen.onkey(tic.two, "2, s")
screen.onkey(tic.three, "3, k")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
screen.onkey(tic.one, "1")
screen.onkey(tic.one, "t")
screen.onkey(tic.two, "2")
screen.onkey(tic.two, "s")
screen.onkey(tic.three, "3")
screen.onkey(tic.three, "k")
screen.listen()
```

Or loop over the posibilities, something like:

```
key_handlers = [(tic.one, "1t"), (tic.two, "2s"), (tic.three, "3k")]

for handler, keys in key_handlers:
    for key in keys:
        screen.onkey(handler, key)

screen.listen()
```